# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap' - precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass, dokku

I'm trying to deploy to Dokku running on a Digital Ocean droplet. When Dokku tries to compile the assets - it fails with the above error. I figured it might be a Dokku thing (coming from heroku where it works) so tried to run `rake assets:precompile` locally so I could push it to my repo and then to Dokku.

Got the same error locally `Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap'`

Here are some relevant lines from my configs:

production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true

config.assets.compress = true

config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = true
```

application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

I'm using these gems and rails 3.2.13:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

I `//= require bootstrap` in my application.js file.

Anyone have tips on how to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently I updated my bundle and didn't look closely. My `bootstrap-sass` gem had updated to 3.2*.

According to their docs:

> Starting with bootstrap-sass v3.1.1.1, due to the structural changes from upstream you will need these backported asset pipeline gems on Rails 3.2.

You can check the [docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master) to see how to backport it if you want, but until I upgrade to Rails 4 I went ahead and moved back to `bootstrap-sass`, '3.1.1.0'`.